# Three hours ( or three thousand pounds ) is or are?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

When can ***three hours*** or ***three thousand pounds*** be considered singular and plural ?

e.g. *Three hours ( is - are ) a long period to wait for you.*

e.g. *Three thousand pounds ( was - were ) collected for charity last week.*

Comment: When the emphasis is on the whole collective thing itself, I'd use singular; conversely when meaning each individual thing I'd use plural eg:
"The sum of three thousand pounds was collected . . ." 
 "Three thousand pound coins were collected . . . "

Answer (score 1):

Quantities or measurements of time, money, distance, weight usually take singular verbs. That is, they are regarded as one unit.

Example:

> Five hundred dollars *is* too much to pay.

See [here](http://college.cengage.com/english/raimes/digitalkeys/keyshtml/subject6.htm) and [here](http://www3.su.edu/cf/writing_center/resources/esl/setvi/prints/setvi3ap.html).